# CSS Keyframes: How to move div to certain position

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div I want to move to a certain position (say [200,200]) when I add the class remove. I have a lot of divs from different places and I want them to meet at [200,200].

```
.remove {   -webkit-animation: swoopOut 2s 1 ease forwards;      }

@-webkit-keyframes swoopOut {
    0% {position: relative; left: 0px; top: 00px; opacity: 1}
    80% {position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 200px; opacity: 1}
    100% {position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 200px; opacity: 0}
}
```

When I use top/left, it moves relative (200 down, 200 right) though I want absolute (to [200,200]). I've tried position: absolute but that won't work.

Any help?

EDIT: I've tried to make an example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzaj9nt5/3/) where I want the two boxes to meet at 150,50. What can I do?

Comment: Please, can you show us your `position: absolute;` try, and explain how exactly that won't work?

Comment: Remember to use absolute realitve to the parent you need to define the position for the parent too... different from static

Comment: [Here you go!](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/tzaj9nt5/) Not worth an answer, so deleted it.

Comment: I've tried to make an example. How can I get the boxes to meet at 150,50? http://jsfiddle.net/tzaj9nt5/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of `div`s? With CSS, I'm pretty sure it's not possible without a `keyframe` rule for each element. With JS, however:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  TweenLite.to(document.getElementsByClassName("box"), 1, {
    top: 50,
    left: 150,
    onComplete: function() {
      TweenLite.to(this.target, 0.2, {
        opacity: 0,
        onComplete: function() {
          TweenLite.set(this.target, {
            opacity: 1
          });
          this.restart();
        }.bind(this)
      });
    }
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  /*position: relative;*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.meet {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="meet"></div>
</div>
```

Here's with CSS only but with multiple `keyframe` and `animation` rules.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.meet {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.box1 {
  -webkit-animation: boxOne 1s infinite;
}
.box2 {
  -webkit-animation: boxTwo 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes boxOne {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    left: 150px;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    left: 150px;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes boxTwo {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 1
  }
  80% {
    left: 150px;
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    left: 150px;
    top: -50px;
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box box1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box box2"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="meet">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the plugin to work neither in Aptana or JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/NicklasMF/q3LLe4o4/

Comment: Yes, because of `window.onload` and the code was specified to run on `onload` (to the left). http://jsfiddle.net/q3LLe4o4/1/

Answer (score -1):

just a simple ball moving left to right

```css
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    
        #container {
          position: relative;
        }
    
    
        .box {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background-color: coral;
          border-radius: 50%;
          
        }
        .box {
          animation: boxOne 3s infinite;
        }
        @keyframes boxOne {
          0% {
            left: 0vw;
            opacity: 1
          }
          100% {
            left: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Here's one that just moves a simple ball, left to right.

Comment: Your answer is very general and doesnt solve the problem that is described in the question. Please review and provide an answer that helps solve the problem directly.